# Is there a tool that allow to get a desired inflected form from a base word (lemne)?

Tags: nlp

I need a tool that takes in argument a word e.g "fast" and another argument specifying the requested part of speech form e.g an adverb
which would output "fastly".

In fact, stemming and lemmatization are a special case of the NLP task I need.

If it exists, does someone know how it's called?
And how correct it is statistically?

The ideal tool would take any inflected form as input.
A less ideal tool but which would still help me would take a base word (lemne) as input.

A bonus would be to be able to not only specify part of speech (e.g verb) but to specify time conjugate and plurality e.g:
arg1: eat arg2: POS->verb time->preterit|singular
output: ate
or arg1: eat arg2: POS->verb time->past participle
output: eaten

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that what you are discussing is possible, the technical term for this is "morphological realisation" or just "realisation". An example library that can do it for you is [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg), though it isn't quite as flexible as you describe (I don't think anything is). To pull some example code from their tutorial:

```
SPhraseSpec p = nlgFactory.createClause();
p.setSubject("Mary");
p.setVerb("chase");
p.setObject("the monkey");
p.setFeature(Feature.TENSE, Tense.PAST);
// output: Mary chased the monkey.
```

Also note "fastly" is not correct English...